# issue on javascript Variables

Tags: javascript, global-variables, google-geocoder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Geocoding service</title>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
            function initialize() {

                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                address = "toronto, canada";

                geocoder.geocode({
                    'address': address
                }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                        var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    } else {
                        var lat = 123;
                        var lng = 456;
                    }
                    document.getElementById('my_place1').value = lat + " - " + lng;
                });

                document.getElementById('my_place').value = lat + " - " + lng;

            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onLoad="initialize()">
        <input name="" id="my_place" style="width:300px; margin-left:20px;" type="text">
        <br>
        <input name="" id="my_place1" style="width:300px; margin-left:20px;" type="text">
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above code for `my_place1` value is working but the same value not working with my_place. Can anybody help to solve this issue? I want to work something outside `geocoder.geocode` with `lat` and `lng` values.

Comment: The operation is **asynchronous**.

Comment: Not only that the variables `lat` and `lng` are out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Your `document.getElementById('my_place').value = lat + " - " + lng ;` 
is executed before `lat` and `lang` are made, which is concept of asynchronous.

When you want to use that outside of `geocoder.geocode(`, then you will have to invoke the callback function `updatdateMyPlace()` after made `lat` and `lang`

**UPDATE**

```
 function initialize() {
      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      address = "toronto, canada";
      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        }
      else {
         var lat = 123;
          var lng = 456;
       }
        document.getElementById('my_place1').value = lat + " - " + lng  ; 
        updatdateMyPlace(lat, lng);
     });

     function updatdateMyPlace(lat, lng){
        document.getElementById('my_place').value = lat + " - " + lng ; 
     }
 }
```

Comment: yea. but i want lat and lng values out side geocoder.geocode(). that is the issue here

Comment: for that you will have invoke callback function after made the `lat` and `lng` values ar made

Comment: you are correct. But the real issue is i want to do something with lat, lng value outside geocoder.geoode(). i want to send this lat, lng values to ouside geocoder.geocode()

Comment: `updatdateMyPlace()` is outside `geocoder.geocode()` function So `lat` and `lang` are. please have a look answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are locally scoping these values, which means you can only access them from within the same block.

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

    document.getElementById('my_place1').value = lat + " - " + lng;

}  // <--- once you exit this block, the lat/lng no longer exist
```

Comment: to use lat and lng values outside the block means, how can i paas them to outside.